# Execution time for printing numbers and list of numbers

Tags: python, range

I am trying to print numbers from 1 to 1000.

`print(*range(1,1001))` is taking more time than printing it's list `print([*range(1,1001)])`.

Any reason printing a list is much faster than printing row of numbers?

Comment: That's odd. They both take the same time (around 0.1 seconds) on my old 2GHz machine running Python 3.6.0. On Linux.

Comment: Most likely either (a) you're on Windows, and running Python in the normal command prompt as your terminal, or (b) you're running your code in some IDE that fakes a terminal. Either way, the problem is that the call to write to your terminal is very slow, so writing 1000 small things takes a lot longer than writing one big thing.

Comment: Could even just be a regular terminal on Linux or something. I see a similar performance difference on my Gnome Terminal on Linux.

Comment: @abarnert could you elaborate a bit on how Windows and Python in cmd affects itt?

Comment: When you say "more time", are you talking about, say, 0.4ms vs. 0.3ms, or are you talking a human-noticeable delay? Because the second one _will_ be faster by probably dozens of microseconds if you time them in a loop, just because you're passing a single argument on the stack instead of 1000.

Comment: @abarnert It is human noticeable delay . timeit.timeit("print(*range(1,1001))",number=1) => 10 s timeit.timeit("print([*range(1,1001)])",number=1) => 95 ms

Comment: BTW,  I am using Windows and running this code on Python IDLE .

Comment: @RaeesulAsad OK, then it's the IDLE fake terminal taking about 10ms for every single `write` that makes the big difference here—exactly the part I explained at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different things you could be asking about here.

---

The second one will be faster just because of things like:

- Passing a single argument instead of 1000. (In recent versions of CPython, this doesn't actually mean passing 1000 values on the stack, but it does mean you have to go through `CALL_FUNCTION_EX` instead of going through the simpler `CALL_FUNCTION`, and in fact its optimized fast path.)
- Looping over the list elements inside the optimized `list.__repr__`, instead of with a generic iterator loop.
- The stuff `print` does between the `__str__` of each element is slightly more complicated than the stuff `list.__repr__` does between the `__repr__` of each element (conditionally printing a local variable, as opposed to always tacking on a constant string).

That should be a matter of microseconds—enough to *measure*, but not enough to *notice*.

---

But the second one will *also* be faster because it's making fewer I/O calls. This is likely to swamp all those little differences. And if your terminal is something slow, like Windows `cmd` or the IDLE fake terminal, this could very easily be enough to notice.

---

First let's try calling a function that does absolutely nothing:

```
In [765]: def dummy(*args): pass    
In [766]: %timeit dummy(*range(1, 1001))
19 µs ± 71.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)    
In [767]: %timeit dummy([*range(1, 1001)])
13 µs ± 609 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

So, the second one is about 50% faster just because of argument passing, but that's only 6us.

---

What if it iterates its arguments, effectively the way `print` does?

```
In [768]: def dummy(*args):
     ...:     for _ in args: pass
In [769]: %timeit dummy(*range(1, 1001))
22.8 µs ± 1.31 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)    
In [770]: %timeit dummy([*range(1, 1001)])
13.1 µs ± 148 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Now it's getting closer to 2:1, but it's still only 9us difference.

Of course I'm cheating here a bit, because `print` is a C function—but, either way, the `*args` gets turned into a tuple that they have to loop over somehow.

---

What if it calls the `__str__` of each of its arguments as well, for a fairer comparison?

```
In [776]: def dummy(*args):
     ...:     for arg in args: str(arg)
In [776]: %timeit dummy(*range(1, 1001))
185 µs ± 1.67 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)    
In [777]: %timeit dummy([*range(1, 1001)])
86.3 µs ± 826 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Even trying to make things more fair to the first one, it's still about 2:1.

---

Let's actually call `print`, but print to a file object that just throws away its inputs:

```
In [747]: class Nully:
     ...:     def write(self, *args): pass
In [749]: null = Nully()    
In [750]: %timeit print(*range(1, 1001), file=null)
390 µs ± 7.44 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)   
In [751]: %timeit print([*range(1, 1001)], file=null)
88.4 µs ± 2.35 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Now the second one is roughly 4x as fast—but we're still only talking a fraction of a millisecond.

---

Now let's try hooking up actual I/O, but to a null device:

```
In [745]: %timeit with open(os.devnull, 'w') as null: print(*range(1, 1001), file=null)
436 µs ± 13.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)    
In [746]: %timeit with open(os.devnull, 'w') as null: print([*range(1, 1001)], file=null)
140 µs ± 1.74 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

They both slowed down by about the same small amount.

---

Now let's try writing to a file that takes a long time—say 10ms—for each write:

```
In [767]: class Slowy:
     ...:     def write(self, *args): time.sleep(0.01)
In [768]: null = Slowy()
In [770]: %timeit print(*range(1, 1001), file=null)
26.8 s ± 15.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [771]: %timeit print([*range(1, 1001)], file=null)
28.2 ms ± 39.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

The original 300us difference is presumably still there, but who cares? It's the 3-orders-of-magnitude 27-second difference caused by 1000 writes instead of 1 that matters here.

Of course even `cmd.exe` and IDLE aren't *that* slow. But they are pretty slow.

So, my guess is, that last part is what you're asking about.

---

In fact, from comments added later:

> It is human noticeable delay .

```
timeit.timeit("print(*range(1,1001))",number=1) => 10 s 
timeit.timeit("print([*range(1,1001)])",number=1) => 95 ms
```

> BTW, I am using Windows and running this code on Python IDLE .

So I was wrong: IDLE *is* almost *exactly* that slow. (Wow!)

Comment: Worth mentioning that the list version will have larger memory overhead. It's not a "free" option to always use lists.

Comment: @jpp Isn't the 3.7 interpreter is going to build a list to handle the splatting in the first case anyway? I'll have to check… (And even in older versions that splatted through the stack, 1000 stack entries is only smaller than a list of 1000 entries by a small constant multiplier for the list slack, which you could solve by using a tuple instead.)

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood, but I thought `print(*range(3))` or `print(0, 1, 2)` don't (in either case) require building a list. But I'm happy to be proven wrong. Reference also `dis.dis('print(*range(3))')`.

Comment: @jpp I have to look at how splat gets passed in 3.6+ and now print does its arg parsing; I’m only about 60% confident here. I’ll get back to you.

Comment: @jpp OK, splat passes the iterable through untouched, then [inside `CALL_FUNCTION_EX`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/ceval.c#L3253) it gets turned into a tuple, and that's what gets passed to the C function as its `args`. So, you will save a bit of memory, but only the same amount you'd save by using a tuple instead of a list.

Comment: @jpp While we're at it, for the first case, the `[*range(1,1001)]` is the slowest part of the original 13us, and using `tuple(range(1,1001))` cuts almost 8% off that time. Not sure that's worth mentioning in the answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be right, this is the output on my machine (Mac OSX)

```
import timeit

# 1
timeit.timeit('print(*range(1,1001))',number=10000)
7.32013652799651

# 2
timeit.timeit('print([*range(1,1001)])',number=10000)
3.6037830549757928
```

I would say that the reason relies in the fact that by using the second method  you are passing to the `print` function a list, while using the first one the `print` function is called with the list of items as individual arguments.

Looking at the output of `dis()`

```
 dis.dis('print(*range(1,10))')

          0 LOAD_NAME                0 (print)
          2 LOAD_NAME                1 (range)
          4 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
          6 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
          8 CALL_FUNCTION            2
         10 CALL_FUNCTION_EX         0
         12 RETURN_VALUE


 dis.dis('print([*range(1,10)])')
          0 LOAD_NAME                0 (print)
          2 LOAD_NAME                1 (range)
          4 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
          6 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
          8 CALL_FUNCTION            2
         10 BUILD_LIST_UNPACK        1
         12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
         14 RETURN_VALUE
```

it is possible to see that in the second case the items of the list are joined (`BUILD_LIST_UNPACK`) before calling the print function.

Answer (score -1):

Printing numbers will yeild one value at a time
Printing list will yeild whole list at a time.

Comment: Just like print(1) print (2) and print([1,2])

Comment: Make sure to explain. I can't understand what exactly you mean.

Comment: I don't think this explains the issue. After all, somewhere you still need to go through that `[1, 2]` and turn it into the string `'[1, 2]'`, which is going to involve looping over all of the elements and calling their `__repr__`, and without more information there's no reason to expect that loop to be faster than the one inside `print` looping over its arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, OP is asking *why* this phenomenon is the case, so you've only echoed OP's observation as an explanation.